# Displaying data from a database in a table using multidimensional arrays, based on a status

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm building a status table  from data in a database. Right now, I'm getting the data and storing it as follows:

```
$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q2r)) {
 $array[] = $row;

}
```

Afterwards, I want to create a table and paint the cells green or red, according to the status I'm retrieving. For this, I'm using a foreach:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $slot => $value) {

            if(is_int($slot)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "is int slot";

                if( $value == 1){
                    echo "<td style=\"background-color:#00FF00\">".PHP_EOL;
                }else{
                    echo "<td style=\"background-color:#FF0000\">".PHP_EOL;
                }

                echo 750+50*$slot ."</td></tr>".PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }

}
```

Right now, sinceI'm retrieving 2 rows from my current test query, this code creates 2 sepparate tables. What I'm trying to achieve is a single table that displays a green cell if the value for that cell is 1, or red if no values for that cell are 1.

For example, if for cell number 1 I retrieve "1" in an array and "0" in the other, I want it to paint the cell green.

Thanks for any help you can give me! Cheers!

edit: vardump on the array output:

```
[0]=>
array(7) {
  ["date"]=>
string(10) "2016-03-11"
[1]=>
string(1) "0"
[2]=>
string(1) "1"
[3]=>
string(1) "1"
[4]=>
string(1) "0"
["doc_id"]=>
string(1) "0"
["day_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
 }
 [1]=>
 array(7) {
["date"]=>
string(10) "2016-03-11"
[1]=>
string(1) "1"
[2]=>
string(1) "0"
[3]=>
string(1) "1"
[4]=>
string(1) "0"
["doc_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
  ["day_id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
 }
  }
```

Comment: what's the problem you are facing? also can you show what `var_dump($array);` outputs?

Comment: why is there a <br /> in the middle of your table?  I'm assuming you have <table> tags before and after the code snipper you're showing.

Comment: Ignore the echo, forgot to take it out, Its not actually doing anything there. I'll add the var_dump on the $array to the main post